# Powerpoint slideshow manipulation

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I'm using a PPT as a tool for my quiz and running into some problems. So basically, I have say slide 4 which asks you to choose easy, med or hard. I've used hyperlinks to redirect from here to slide 5, 6 or 7 depending on the player's choice.

Then I want the slideshow to automatically move to slide 8 regardless of which slide I'm on (5, 6 or 7). Similarly, slide 8 will send the show to 9, 10 or 11, each of which should redirect to 12, and so on for multiple rounds.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Hide slides 5,6,7,8,20,11 and so on. You will then be able to link to it, but not click to it.

Comment: Doesn't work. Once I go from slide 4 to 5 or 6; it takes me next to the next slide (even though it's hidden) instead of slide 8.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried everything I could think of to make what you're asking for work, but it doesn't seem possible.

Do you absolutely need to create this quiz with PowerPoint? If not, there are plenty of Quiz creator websites you can use, like this one:

https://www.onlinequizcreator.com/

They seem to allow for unlimited free quiz creation as long as the quiz is less than 15 questions.

Comment: I have 45 questions :P. Besides, I won't have access to internet at the location, so I have to pre-prepare a powerpoint and take it there.

Comment: Oh, dang. Well...if you are at all familiar with the vba editor in MS Office, you could create macros that display message boxes after clicking the right/wrong answer on each slide and completely bypass the hidden slide issue. But that's assuming your response to each answer is short text/doesn't require images. Either way, maybe this might help you:

http://www.ellenfinkelstein.com/pptblog/easily-create-a-quiz-in-powerpoint-using-visual-basic-for-applications/

Comment: I'm not familiar with that.... I don't have adequate time to learn that. I guess I'll make do without it for today (maybe use hyperlinks) and learn vba editing later. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What your trying to accomplish isn't something Powerpoint lends itself to very well.

I think you might do a lot better looking into something like a 'Choose your own adventure' program.